# Как работает GOMAXPROCS и параллельность в Golang?

Tags: многопоточность, golang

Когда мы создаем горутины я так понимаю создаются условно такие "потоки приложения" которые на самом деле внутри одного потока ОС.

Как тогда достигается реальная параллельность когда у нас не асинхронно, а именно одновременно выполняется код на разных ядрах?

Я так понимаю мы же не можешь из приложения перенаправить код на другие ядра, это должна сделать ОС ?

Нашел такое объяснение

```
Планировщик среды выполнения Go использует параметр GOMAXPROCS, чтобы определить, сколько
потоков ОС необходимо использовать для одновременного выполнения кода Go. Значение по
умолчанию - это количество ядер ЦП на машине. Например, на 8-ядерной машине планировщик
отправляет код Go 8 потокам ОС одновременно (GOMAXPROCS - n в планировании m: n).
```

Т.е. получается в момент старта программы мы просим у ОС сразу запустить 8 потоков, а в процессе выполнения программы распределяем задачи между ними?

И это будут не потоки "внутри приложения", а все таки реально разные потоки ОС ?

Comment: Всё ваше приложение работает конкурентно (синхронно), даже если GOMAXPROCS показывает 8. И так, вы попали в свой main.go и далее по коду приложения, где-то вы наткнетесь на инструкцию `go func (){ //do something }()`. В данном примере, нас интересует ключевое слово `go`, оно запускает такой механизм как `gorutine`, именно этот механизм помогает вам добиться многопоточного исполнения. В то время, пока ваша программа работает в отдельном (""основном"") потоке, участок кода (метод/функция) запущенный через `go` будет выполнен в другом.

Comment: Если ранее работали с RebbitMQ или Apach Kafka, то вам это будет близко, т.к. принцип тот же, у вас имеется основное приложение работающее синхронно и только какие-то его специфичные участки запускаются асинхронно (параллельно ""основному"" потоку).

Comment: А правильно ли будет сказать что если GOMAXPROCS = 1 то если даже у меня запускается 3 горутины то по сути они будут выполнятся асинхронно но в одном потоке?

Comment: Да, верно. Более подробно, можно глянуть тут (неплохая статья): https://habr.com/ru/post/337528/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вы правильно понимаете процесс работы горутин в Go. Горутины являются условными "потоками" приложения, которые могут быть исполнены одновременно с другими горутинами внутри одного потока ОС. Однако Go предоставляет механизмы, которые позволяют распределять горутины на разные ядра ЦП для одновременного исполнения.

Параметр GOMAXPROCS указывает, сколько потоков ОС необходимо использовать для одновременного исполнения кода Go. По умолчанию это значение равно количеству ядер ЦП на компьютере. Например, на 8-ядерной машине GOMAXPROCS будет равно 8, что означает, что планировщик Go будет использовать 8 потоков ОС для одновременного исполнения кода Go.

Когда вы запускаете горутину, планировщик Go распределяет ее на один из потоков ОС, который указан в GOMAXPROCS. Если все потоки ОС уже заняты, то горутина будет ожидать, пока один из потоков ОС освободится. Таким образом, использование горутин позволяет распараллелить код на разных ядрах ЦП, что повышает производительность приложения.

Однако следует иметь в виду, что использование горутин не гарантирует, что ваш код будет выполняться одновременно на разных ядрах ЦП. Это зависит от реализации ОС, которая может использовать различные механизмы для распределения потоков ОС на разные ядра ЦП.